# How to solve error: Value UPDATE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an app in this I used two spinners when I click on spinner item the selected item should insert into the mysql database, i am using following code but it gives error i.e "Value UPDATE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"  at SignupActivity1.java page in "onPostExecute" method.
How do i solve this?
Please suggest me.

SpinnerActivity .java

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity {

        Context ctx = this;
        String ride_root, cab_type, email;
        private boolean loggedIn = false;
        TextView textView, textView1, textView2;

        Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
        Button submit;
        private ArrayList<String> students1;
        private ArrayList<String> students2;
        private JSONArray result1, result2, result;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);
            submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3_user);
           // textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3_s1);
           // textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3_s2);

            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
                    String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");
                    //Showing the current logged in email to textview
                    // textView.setText("Current User: " + email);
                    textView.setText(email);


                    if(loggedIn){
                        //We will start the Profile Activity

                        submitForm();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SpinnerActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
            });

            final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> sAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rides));
            spinner1.setAdapter(sAdapter1);


            final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<String> sAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cabtype));
            spinner2.setAdapter(sAdapter2);

            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ride_root = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                  //  textView1.setText(ride_root);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                   cab_type = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                  //  textView2.setText(cab_type);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }

        private void submitForm() {

            email=textView.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new SignupActivity1(this).execute(ride_root,cab_type,email);
        }
    }
```

SignupActivity1.java

```
    public class SignupActivity1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Context context;
        Boolean error, success;

        public SignupActivity1(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String ride_root = arg0[0];
            String cab_type = arg0[1];
            String email = arg0[2];

            String link;
            String data;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader;
            String result;

            try {

                data = "?ride_root=" + URLEncoder.encode(ride_root, "UTF-8");
                data += "&cab_type=" + URLEncoder.encode(cab_type, "UTF-8");
                data += "&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");

                link = "http://example.in/Spinner/spinnerU.php" + data;

                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                // return null;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            String jsonStr = result;
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                    if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Success! Your are Now MangoAir User.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Looks Like you already have Account with US.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON Please data Fill all the records.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Toast.makeText(context, "Please LogIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Grrr! Check your Internet Connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

php file

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$id=$_GET["email"];
$ride_root=$_GET["ride_root"];
$cab_type=$_GET["cab_type"]; 

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET ride_root='$ride_root', cab_type='$cab_type' WHERE id='$id'";
// echo $sql;
// $r=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                    echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
                }else{
                    '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
                }

            mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Could you write the string you are getting in the onPostExecute() method? Probably the string you are getting there is not a valid JSON.

Comment: are you sure that the `echo $sql;` is commented in your running code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in onPost:

```
Log.e("JSON respons",String.valueof(jsonstr));
Log.e("JSON respons",String.valueof(query_result));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to checkout the jsonStr in logcat  to see the formate of response of your Url. either is in JASONArray form or in JASONObject form. After that you have to fetch Data in onPost.

I think your Response is not in JASONObject form.

Comment: this is my url in logcat i.e "http://example.in/Spinner/spinnerU.php?ride_root=Nashik-Pune&cab_type=Ac&email=gfg%40gh.hj"

Comment: {"query_result":"SUCCESS"} this is output of this url in browser

Comment: but records not upadate in table